# TikzExternal combined with Bitmap Graphics Export

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I currently use the TikzExternal package, which can be used after all my external tikz figures have been created and allows faster subsequent compilations. Below is a snippet from the pgfplots manual. Note the basic usage is to comment out the includes for tikz and pgfplots and add then use the tikzexternal package:

[image: tikzexternal]

This functionality is working fine. Next, I want to convert some of my vector images to bitmap to improve performance when viewing the pdf. I'm following the guide from the pgf manual:

[image: bitmap]

Since I need to create the .png files, I first switch off tikzexternal temporarily,  add the \tikzset{png export} setting and force rebuild of the plots that I want to make as a png. Then, sure enough, the desired plots are now bitmaps.

Now, what I want to do is switch back on the tikzexternal functionality to save compile time again, and that is where I run into issues: all of the images that use the \tikzset{png export} setting do not work and throw errors related to pgfexternal@restore since that macro is no longer defined. As far as I can tell it is defined using "\def\pgfexternal@restore#1{#1}" somewhere deep in pgfplots. Now, if I use that definition, the error does go away, but now the bitmap images aren't used, and instead the original vector pdfs are used. What can I do to make TikzExternal and the png export style compatible? Seems like many macros need redefining, but it's beyond my latex knowledge on how to fix. Please advise.

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzexternal}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzset{
  png export/.style={
    external/system call/.add=
      {}
      {; convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"},
    %
    /pgf/images/external info,
    /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
      \includegraphics
        [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]
        {##1.png}%
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \tikzset{png export}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I nearly found a potential solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzexternal}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{pgfplots}{ 
   \tikzset{
    png export/.style={
      external/system call/.add={}{
        && convert -density 600 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"},
      /pgf/images/external info,
      /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
        \includegraphics
          [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]
          {##1.png}%
      },
    }
  }
  \newcommand{\makethispng}{\tikzset{png export}}
}
{
  \newcommand{\makethispng}{
  \def\pgfincludeexternalgraphics##1{%
    \begingroup
    \pgfexternalreaddpth{##1}%
        \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics
        %[width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight] % this is the one line not working
        {##1.png}}%
    \ifdim\pgfretval=0pt
        \box1
    \else
        \dimen0=\pgfretval\relax
        \hbox{\lower\dimen0 \box1 }%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
  }
  \def\pgfexternal@restore#1{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\tikzexternalize

\tikzset{
  png export/.style={
    external/system call/.add=
      {}
      {; convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"},
    %
    /pgf/images/external info,
    /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
      \includegraphics
        [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]
        {##1.png}%
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  %\tikzset{png export}
  \makethispng
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The only issue now is setting the width/height of the bitmap using the saved info in the .dpth file. They are available in the .dpth file but I'm having trouble loading them into \pgfexternalwidth and \pgfexternalheight. The error I'm getting is

```
    "! Undefined control sequence.
    \Gin@@ewidth ->\pgfexternalwidth"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Matt But preloading the already created bitmap is already external isn't it? Becauase, what I understood from your question, correct me if I am wrong, is you first externalise to compile your graphics, then convert them to png, then when you use externalise again it throws errors. I think that is the intended functionality per se. Because, I think, what you are saying is, you want to do a special sort of externalisation where you can directly influence bimaps. What I do not understand is why do you want to externalise graphics which are already in bitmaps?

Comment: @JouleV OP did not give us any code yet. OP only pointed us to a reference in the manual ;).

Comment: @Raaja yes it's external, sure. But the issue is still the long compile, which doesn't get better until I use the tikzexternal package. Basically the tikzexternal packages lets it go straight to an \includeimage command using the already built figures right away without any of the overhead.

Comment: @Matt Yeah yeah, that I understand. But now what you ask for basically is to mimic this function to work with `.bitmaps` right? May be one dirty way I could think of is to create a macro on top of the export and then check if the `bitmaps` exists. If they do, then include them directly, else compile the `.tex` file to generate pdf and then do the `export` (as now you are doing). And, then continue the cycle.

Comment: @Raaja Right exactly. And to clarify, my document has a combination of both bitmaps and vector graphics, so the solution needs to work with both options.